# A Book where an Animal is advertising itself to be eaten

Tags: story-identification

I remember having read (at least I think I've been reading, it might have been a series but I'm almost positive it was in prose) a book or story where an animal, maybe genetically engineered? basically advertised itself to be eaten.

Something along the lines:

"Have you considered *this* piece of me? Very tasty, I insist you try it."

Now it's a washed out memory so the strongest associations to it are the obvious ridicule of the situation and the protagonist being, as far as I remember it, weirded out / confused / speechless at the situation.

I realize this might be a long-shot but I can't get it out of my head.

Comment: Sounds like a line from Douglas Adams' Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy series, specifically The Restaurant at the End of the Universe.

Comment: See also Monty Python's [Restaurant Abuse sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O1rHYWH8MY).

Comment: I wonder if the *Lion King* scene drew inspiration from here. "Come and have a dine on this tasty swine".

Comment: The animal in question is the Ameglian Major Cow, which was bred to want to be eaten.

Comment: This just made me think of the [Simpson's episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCG7o5VCX4A) featuring 'The Pig of Eden'

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The Restaurant at the end of the Universe, by Douglas Adams.
The scene is recounted here: http://www.sci.fi/~huuhilo/dna2.html

> A large dairy animal approached Zaphod Beeblebrox's table, 
>   a large fat meaty quadruped of the bovine type with
>   large watery eyes, small horns and what might almost have
>   been an ingratiating smile on its lips.
>
> 'Good evening', it lowed and sat back heavily on its haunches, 
>   'I am the main Dish of the Day. May I interest you in the parts 
>   of my body?'

Comment: So it actually was Douglas Adams after all; I couldn't find the scene so I dismissed the book :/

Comment: @dot_Sp0T dismissing HHGTTG, for any reason, is generally a huge mistake. :P

Answer (score 54):

It sounds like it's  from [*The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe) by Douglas Adams, part for his Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy novels, which were originally radio shows for BBC Radio 4.

In the TV show the animal was played by [Peter Davison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Davison), who was married to the actress that played Trillian in that version. He was at the time best known for playing a vet in the show 'All Creatures Great and Small' and would later play the Doctor in Dr Who.

This is a YouTube link to the scene in the show:

Comment: I've heard that he had already accepted the part of The Doctor before being in HHGTTG. He was only allowed to be in it because he was completely unrecognisable in both appearance and voice, so as to not "tarnish" the image of Doctor Who.

Comment: @CJDennis: That's strange, considering that the character he played in "All Creatures" was indistinguishable from the Fifth Doctor in appearance and voice (and very similar in costume, IIRC!), and was a feckless nitwit.

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like "The Restaurant at the End of the Universe" by Douglas Adams

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of why this is what the OP is looking for?